# Download a Readable stream to Zip file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, download

Currently, I make a fetch request, which returns a readable stream (response body is a ReadableStream). I'm trying to save this to a users device as a zip file.

```
getDownload(id, downloadName).then(download => {
            const blob = new Blob([download]);

            const link = document.createElement("a");
            link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download = "fileName";
            link.target = "_blank";
            link.setAttribute("type", "hidden");

            document.body.appendChild(link);

            link.click();
            link.remove();
})
```

This however, downloads into a text file with the contents

```
[object Response]
```

I know that the response is not corrupted, as I have been able to stream it in Chrome, however, this functionality is being added, so I can download in Safari.

How can I get the readable stream downloaded as a zip directory?

Comment: This isn't going to solve your problem but you can get a more useful response by doing the following. `const res = await download.blob()` and pass this into `new Blob([res]);`. Be sure to add `.then(async download => {` here as well

Comment: I solved this issue in my own post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63942715/how-to-download-a-readablestream-on-the-browser-that-has-been-returned-from-fetc/63946003#63946003