# How to download a ReadableStream on the browser that has been returned from fetch

Tags: javascript, browser, download, fetch-api

I am receiving a ReadableStream from a server, returned from my fetch call.

A ReadableStream is returned but I don't know how to trigger a download from this stage. I can't use the url in an href because it requires an Authorization token.

I don't want to install `fs` on the client so what options do I have?

```
  try {
    const res = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
      }
    });

    const blob = await res.blob();

    const newBlob = new Blob([blob]);
    const newUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);

    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = newUrl;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'filename');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.parentNode.removeChild(link);

    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(newBlob);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

Update 1

I converted the file to a Blob, then passed it into a newly generated href. Successfully downloaded a file. The end result was the ReadStream contents as a .txt file.

Meaning stuff like this

```
x:ÚêÒÓ%¶âÜTb∞\Üƒ
```

Comment: there are a lot of information on how to use readable streams here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams

Comment: for example you can do `stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('file.txt'));`

Comment: I would need to install `fs` on the browser to do what is in the second comment which really isn't recommended, you even need to install a weird version that is like 0.0.1-security from what I remember to make it work

Comment: Ah are you doing this request in browser? and want to trigger it to "download the file"?

Comment: What about this? https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js

Comment: I am trying to trigger the file down yes, I will give that package a try

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I have found 2 solutions, both worked but I was missing a simple addition to make them work.

The native solution is

```
  try {
    const res = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });

    const blob = await res.blob();
    const newBlob = new Blob([blob]);

    const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);

    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = blobUrl;
    link.setAttribute('download', `${filename}.${extension}`);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.parentNode.removeChild(link);

    // clean up Url
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
```

This version is using the npm package steamSaver for anyone who would prefer it.

```
  try {
    const res = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });

    const fileStream = streamSaver.createWriteStream(`${filename}.${extension}`);
    const writer = fileStream.getWriter();

    const reader = res.body.getReader();

    const pump = () => reader.read()
      .then(({ value, done }) => {
        if (done) writer.close();
        else {
          writer.write(value);
          return writer.ready.then(pump);
        }
      });

    await pump()
      .then(() => console.log('Closed the stream, Done writing'))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The key for why it was not working was because I did not include the extension, so it either errored out because the mimetype was wrong or it opens a .txt file with a string of the body instead of the image.

Comment: I am getting this error `TypeError: data.blob is not a function`

Comment: Which of the above versions are you using? Did you try to log data before calling blob to make sure that it came in as expected and that you had an async/await for it as well?

Comment: On the first solution, the filesystem dialog will be opened only when the whole body has been read. For large filesystem this can be confusing from a UX perspective. Users expect to see the donwloading status.

Answer (score 1):

I use [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) to download a ReadableStream

```
import FileSaver from 'file-saver';

// ...

const res = await fetch("YOUR_URL", requestOptions);

const blob = await res.blob();

FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "test.zip");
```